# Javascript TinyMCE and Tinybox2

Tags: javascript, tinymce, modalpopup

I am using [tinyMCE][1] and [tinybox2][2] i can get both to work independently but what i am tryng to achieve is that i click on edit button tinybox2 opens the url with the relevant id string on the page the link opens up this has tinyMCE on it with the update form, but i dont understand why tinymce does not load within the popup.

Is there a way to allow javascript to go to this popup of tinybox? or why is it preventing more javascript to load?

Thanks for any help :D

I have done this so far:

1. `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>`
2. get test.php content via $.ajax();  -*no idea on this one*-
3. `<p><a class="Forumusername" onclick="TINY.box.show({url:'test.php',width:750,height:300})">CLICK ME</a>`
4. reinit TinyMCE editor with tinyMCE.init call. -*i dont know how to implement this either*-

Edited links but question is answered.

Comment: I would recommend not using tinybox.
It's undocumented and only comes as obfuscated javascript, that's a big no go.
Either you'd need a perfect working script with good docs or a normal source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not good in updating old code, so I will rewrite it completely. That's content of two my files `test.php` and `edit.php`:

test.php

```
<!doctype html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/tinybox2/style.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinybox2/tinybox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#open_editor').click(function(){
        $.get(this.href).done(function(html){
            TINY.box.show({ 
                html: html,
                width: 500, 
                height: 400, 
                openjs: function(){
                    tinyMCE.init({ mode: 'textareas', theme: 'advanced' });
                }
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
    tinyMCE.init({ mode: 'textareas', theme: 'advanced' });
});
</script>

<a id="open_editor" href="edit.php">Open editor</a>

<textarea></textarea>
```

edit.php

```
<textarea name="body" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Correct paths to stylesheets and scripts before running `test.php`.

These scripts are checked and tested.

Comment: Hi Martinez, i'm not sure what you mean with jQuery loaded sorry im barely getting my head around javascript, i also cant use an iframe it works i know that as i can go to the pages directly and tinymce works fine, but using an iframe earlier when i submitted data it reloaded the iframe i really need the url feature if possible

Comment: OK, I see you have modified your test.php again and stripped jQuery.ready :) Just check the second reason and add iframe:'test.php' parameter.

Comment: ah sorry i was trying something another post said but i didnt understand it. will add iframe but it will not help what i'm trying to achieve lets say the content loaded in the iframe was an update php script once submitted the redirect is within the iframe and is still within a popup.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't read your post to the end. If you cannot use frames, then load jQuery in the head of test.php and wrap tinyMCE.init into jQuery.ready(function(){ .... }) again. This should help.

Comment: The page that produced the popup should be reloaded from the popups actions, why does tinyMCE not load when it is within the url?

Comment: Hi Martinez, could you help me load and wrap tinymce i will put a clear text page up of what i think i need to do and test.

Comment: Because tinyMCE.init initialize editor **only once** since the page is loaded. Change your tinyMCE.init call in test.php to: _window.onload = function(){ tinyMCE.init({ .... }); }_

Comment: Sorry about this Martinez i wrapped it like the last comment but tinyMCE does not show. i will try the jquery using 2 other test pages

Comment: Sorry, Carl. I'm completely confused with iframe/url method. You should not use window.onload without iframe. All you need is: 1. load jQuery; 2. get test.php content via $.ajax(); 3. open TINYBOX with html:page_content; 4. reinit TinyMCE editor with tinyMCE.init call.

Comment: Just forgot to say that all steps must be done in main script -test1.php, not in test.php

Comment: ok think i'm getting lost now.. this is how it needs to work ztest2.php is the content > user clicks edit which loads up the post to be edited in a popup user clicks submit popup closes sending a redirect to reload the page.         I have the php working fine all i need is for the url feature to load the tinymce within the popup (the php is not in the test pages to simplify testing).

Comment: Martinez i have updated the description above really appreciate your time here but some of the steps i'm not sure how to write it. anyway you could send me a modified example?

Comment: Thank you onsite in London today will test when I get home

Comment: Hi Again Martinez, i have updated test.php and test1.php but it does not load the content in the pop up just writes the text test.php

Comment: I got it working, Carl. Just add 'openjs' parameter with callback, which initializes editor. (See answer update) I've just checked in on my localhost.

Comment: still no joy can you see my test.php and test1.php what have i done worng or on my link to open popup is wrong? it just displays test.php as text :(

Comment: Try to copy the code from update again. Seems like I've copied incorrect fragment from my source. :(

Comment: $('a.Formusername').click(function(){

Comment: I've rewritten my answer completely since I confused alot during editing old code.

Comment: I cannot help you anymore. These my scripts work as you can see here: http://ostgals.lv/test.php

Comment: Thank you Martinez no idea why it didnt show for me but using your examples works great... sorry for all the time you had to spend really appreciate it.